# How do I get value from different private sub

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to VB, I've received an assignment from my teacher to create a CGPA Calculator. [This is the form.](http://i.imgur.com/pgC68VD.png)
As you can see, I'm trying to get the values from "credit hours" then sum them up and display it on "total ch". How do I do so? These values are from different private sub, so they're not globally available. Can someone explain to me on how can I get the values? Or perhaps are there better/easier way to do it?

Below are my codes

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbocid0.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim coursename As String
    Dim credithour As Integer

    If cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        coursename = "Computer System & Applications"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        coursename = "Discrete Structures"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        coursename = "Program Design"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 1"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 2"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        coursename = "Database Systems"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        coursename = "Contemporary Management & Entrepreneurship"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
        coursename = "English"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
        coursename = "Business Management"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
        coursename = "Computer Architecture"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 10 Then
        coursename = "Operating Systems"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 11 Then
        coursename = "Systems Analysis & Design"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 12 Then
        coursename = "Data Communications & Networking"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 13 Then
        coursename = "Internet & Web Publishing"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 14 Then
        coursename = "Object Oriented Programming"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 15 Then
        coursename = "Programming In Java"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 16 Then
        coursename = "Data Structure & Algorithms"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 17 Then
        coursename = "Computing Project"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 18 Then
        coursename = "Effective Communication Skills"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 19 Then
        coursename = "E-Commerce"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 20 Then
        coursename = "Multimedia Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 21 Then
        coursename = "Management Information System"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 22 Then
        coursename = "Programming For Business Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 23 Then
        coursename = "Industrial Training"
        credithour = "6"
    End If
    txtcname0.Text = coursename
    txtch0.Text = credithour
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbocid1.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim coursename As String
    Dim credithour As Integer

    If cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        coursename = "Computer System & Applications"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        coursename = "Discrete Structures"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        coursename = "Program Design"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 1"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 2"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        coursename = "Database Systems"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        coursename = "Contemporary Management & Entrepreneurship"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
        coursename = "English"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
        coursename = "Business Management"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
        coursename = "Computer Architecture"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 10 Then
        coursename = "Operating Systems"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 11 Then
        coursename = "Systems Analysis & Design"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 12 Then
        coursename = "Data Communications & Networking"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 13 Then
        coursename = "Internet & Web Publishing"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 14 Then
        coursename = "Object Oriented Programming"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 15 Then
        coursename = "Programming In Java"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 16 Then
        coursename = "Data Structure & Algorithms"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 17 Then
        coursename = "Computing Project"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 18 Then
        coursename = "Effective Communication Skills"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 19 Then
        coursename = "E-Commerce"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 20 Then
        coursename = "Multimedia Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 21 Then
        coursename = "Management Information System"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 22 Then
        coursename = "Programming For Business Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 23 Then
        coursename = "Industrial Training"
        credithour = "6"
    End If
    txtcname1.Text = coursename
    txtch1.Text = credithour
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox10_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtcname2.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox8_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtcname0.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub cbocid2_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbocid2.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim coursename As String
    Dim credithour As Integer

    If cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        coursename = "Computer System & Applications"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        coursename = "Discrete Structures"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        coursename = "Program Design"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 1"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 2"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        coursename = "Database Systems"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        coursename = "Contemporary Management & Entrepreneurship"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
        coursename = "English"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
        coursename = "Business Management"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
        coursename = "Computer Architecture"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 10 Then
        coursename = "Operating Systems"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 11 Then
        coursename = "Systems Analysis & Design"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 12 Then
        coursename = "Data Communications & Networking"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 13 Then
        coursename = "Internet & Web Publishing"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 14 Then
        coursename = "Object Oriented Programming"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 15 Then
        coursename = "Programming In Java"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 16 Then
        coursename = "Data Structure & Algorithms"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 17 Then
        coursename = "Computing Project"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 18 Then
        coursename = "Effective Communication Skills"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 19 Then
        coursename = "E-Commerce"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 20 Then
        coursename = "Multimedia Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 21 Then
        coursename = "Management Information System"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 22 Then
        coursename = "Programming For Business Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 23 Then
        coursename = "Industrial Training"
        credithour = "6"
    End If
    txtcname2.Text = coursename
    txtch2.Text = credithour
End Sub

Private Sub cbocid3_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbocid3.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim coursename As String
    Dim credithour As Integer

    If cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        coursename = "Computer System & Applications"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        coursename = "Discrete Structures"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        coursename = "Program Design"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 1"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 2"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        coursename = "Database Systems"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        coursename = "Contemporary Management & Entrepreneurship"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
        coursename = "English"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
        coursename = "Business Management"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
        coursename = "Computer Architecture"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 10 Then
        coursename = "Operating Systems"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 11 Then
        coursename = "Systems Analysis & Design"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 12 Then
        coursename = "Data Communications & Networking"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 13 Then
        coursename = "Internet & Web Publishing"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 14 Then
        coursename = "Object Oriented Programming"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 15 Then
        coursename = "Programming In Java"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 16 Then
        coursename = "Data Structure & Algorithms"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 17 Then
        coursename = "Computing Project"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 18 Then
        coursename = "Effective Communication Skills"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 19 Then
        coursename = "E-Commerce"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 20 Then
        coursename = "Multimedia Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 21 Then
        coursename = "Management Information System"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 22 Then
        coursename = "Programming For Business Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 23 Then
        coursename = "Industrial Training"
        credithour = "6"
    End If
    txtcname3.Text = coursename
    txtch3.Text = credithour
End Sub

Private Sub cbocid4_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbocid4.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim coursename As String
    Dim credithour As Integer

    If cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        coursename = "Computer System & Applications"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        coursename = "Discrete Structures"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        coursename = "Program Design"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 1"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 2"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        coursename = "Database Systems"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        coursename = "Contemporary Management & Entrepreneurship"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
        coursename = "English"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
        coursename = "Business Management"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
        coursename = "Computer Architecture"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 10 Then
        coursename = "Operating Systems"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 11 Then
        coursename = "Systems Analysis & Design"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 12 Then
        coursename = "Data Communications & Networking"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 13 Then
        coursename = "Internet & Web Publishing"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 14 Then
        coursename = "Object Oriented Programming"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 15 Then
        coursename = "Programming In Java"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 16 Then
        coursename = "Data Structure & Algorithms"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 17 Then
        coursename = "Computing Project"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 18 Then
        coursename = "Effective Communication Skills"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 19 Then
        coursename = "E-Commerce"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 20 Then
        coursename = "Multimedia Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 21 Then
        coursename = "Management Information System"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 22 Then
        coursename = "Programming For Business Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 23 Then
        coursename = "Industrial Training"
        credithour = "6"
    End If
    txtcname4.Text = coursename
    txtch4.Text = credithour
End Sub

Private Sub cbocid5_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbocid5.SelectedIndexChanged
    Dim coursename As String
    Dim credithour As Integer

    If cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
        coursename = "Computer System & Applications"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
        coursename = "Discrete Structures"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 2 Then
        coursename = "Program Design"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 3 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 1"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 4 Then
        coursename = "Mathematical Techniques 2"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 5 Then
        coursename = "Database Systems"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 6 Then
        coursename = "Contemporary Management & Entrepreneurship"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 7 Then
        coursename = "English"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 8 Then
        coursename = "Business Management"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 9 Then
        coursename = "Computer Architecture"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 10 Then
        coursename = "Operating Systems"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 11 Then
        coursename = "Systems Analysis & Design"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 12 Then
        coursename = "Data Communications & Networking"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 13 Then
        coursename = "Internet & Web Publishing"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 14 Then
        coursename = "Object Oriented Programming"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 15 Then
        coursename = "Programming In Java"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 16 Then
        coursename = "Data Structure & Algorithms"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 17 Then
        coursename = "Computing Project"
        credithour = "4"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 18 Then
        coursename = "Effective Communication Skills"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 19 Then
        coursename = "E-Commerce"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 20 Then
        coursename = "Multimedia Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 21 Then
        coursename = "Management Information System"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 22 Then
        coursename = "Programming For Business Applications"
        credithour = "3"
    ElseIf cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 23 Then
        coursename = "Industrial Training"
        credithour = "6"
    End If
    txtcname5.Text = coursename
    txtch5.Text = credithour
End Sub

Sub ClearAll()
    cbocid0.SelectedIndex = 24
    cbocid1.SelectedIndex = 24
    cbocid2.SelectedIndex = 24
    cbocid3.SelectedIndex = 24
    cbocid4.SelectedIndex = 24
    cbocid5.SelectedIndex = 24
End Sub

Private Sub GroupBox1_Enter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GroupBox1.Enter

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub

Private Sub txttotalch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txttotalch.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub btncal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btncal.Click

End Sub

Private Sub txtch0_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtch0.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub btnclear_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnclear.Click
    ClearAll()
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: Declare your course and credit variables at form level. Then set them in the combo change events as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, move your variables out of the sub to the top below the class to make them global.
You only have one variable for credit hour (credithour) so each time you edit a value from any of the combo boxes you are only ever changing one value. Set a variable for each of the number of credit hour values you require and create a variable for the total
`dim totalCH as integer`

Then at the end of each procedure simply type something like `totalCH = credithour1 + credithour2...`

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you create a class level attribute that is dictionary of tuples. Where the key is the index, and the value is a tuple of course name and credit hour. Then all of your functions can stop duplicating so much code and just pull from the dictionary. You will need to initialize your dictionary in your constructor.